# Is it possible to set up domain controller replication in Azure between two resource groups?

Tags: azure

I have a resource group that is running three VMs.  A DC, IIS server and a SQL server.  I have configured backups but I also want to replicate my domain controller to another resource group at a separate geolocation.  Is this possible?  I cannot configure replication with the backup recovery vaults because I am using managed disks on my VMs.  This function is not supported yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to deploy to two different locations inside Azure then you are going to need to do this with two separate vNets (as vNets are in a region) and then join them together. The easiest way to do this today is using vNet peering, this allows you to connect two vNets together (either in the same region or now in separate regions) without the need to configure VPNs, so much simpler. Note that cross region peering is currently in preview.

Once you do this you can then just configure AD replication as you would normally.

Setting up peering can be done in the portal, PowerShell or ARM templates, documentation:

- vNet Peering - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview
- Global Peering Perview - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/global-vnet-peering-preview/

Comment: I was not aware of this feature (I guess it’s new) and this should be the accepted answer. Also I think you have a typo. The last sentence in the first paragraph is supposed to start with “note”?

Comment: I followed the article for the vNet Peering and the PowerShell cmdlet for `Register-AzureRmProviderFeature` did not like the `-AllowGlobalVnetPeering` switch.  Are you sure that this feature is available?

Comment: What regions are you using? It is still in preview so the regions are limited to the following at the min - US West Central, Canada Central, US West 2, Korea South, UK South, UK West, Canada East, India South, India Central, and India West

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since virtual networks can't span resource groups, you'll have to join the two virtual networks that the DCs are in. That means you'll have to create a VPN from one virtual network in one resource group to the other virtual network in the other resource group. Once that is established, you should be able to spin up a VM in the new resource group, join it to the domain and add the AD role and services to it.

Comment: A couple of corrections here - 1. You don't need a VPN to connect to Azure vNets you can use cross region vNet peering. 2. You don't have to use 2 vnets, a VM can join a vNet that is in another resource group, it just makes visibility of what resources are used by what a bit harder.

Comment: @SamCogan Soinds like you should post a better answer. I haven’t been an Azure user for several months and haven’t tried to join two different resource groups in a couple years, so it sounds like things have changed while I wasn’t paying attention. But I don’t understand the options you suggest so it doesn’t seem like I should try to edit to make my answer correct.

Comment: @SamCogan Can you provide me with some documentation that I can read up on to set this up?

Comment: @T4RH33L see my answer